# Why does python say it does not have the file in the directory when there is the file in the directory?

Tags: python, file, directory, ioerror

I am using python, and I am running the script that use the file in the same directory, but it keeps giving me the error saying that there is no such file.
I am using that script file as a module to enable my other script file, by the way. The file I am using as a module is from the github project : https://github.com/nik0spapp/unsupervised_sentiment (unsupervised sentiment analysis)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentiment_analysis.py", line 21, in <module>
    import sentiment as unsupervised_sentiment
  File "/Users/chlee021690/Desktop/Programming/Python/Recommender System/unsupervised_sentiment/sentiment.py", line 20, in <module>
    from hp_classifiers import HpObj, HpSubj
  File "/Users/chlee021690/Desktop/Programming/Python/Recommender System/unsupervised_sentiment/hp_classifiers.py", line 16, in <module>
    from lexicon import Lexicon    
  File "/Users/chlee021690/Desktop/Programming/Python/Recommender System/unsupervised_sentiment/lexicon.py", line 17, in <module>
    from datasets.emoticons_patch import patch_emoticons 
  File "/Users/chlee021690/Desktop/Programming/Python/Recommender System/unsupervised_sentiment/datasets/emoticons_patch.py", line 23, in <module>
    emoticons_file = open("emoticons.data","r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'emoticons.data'
```

Any help would be the best to me as of now. Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you specify the full path?

Comment: you mean like this? lib_path = os.path.abspath("/Users/chlee021690/Desktop/Programming/Python/Recommender System/unsupervised_sentiment/") sys.path.append(lib_path)
import sentiment as unsupervised_sentiment

Comment: I mean just the full path to `/dir/dir/emoticons.data` Obviously dir means whatever your dirs are.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to call the file in question?  It's kinda hard to figure out what's wrong if we can't see what you're doing.

Comment: I mean I can see what's happening in the traceback , but the exact context would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible when using relative paths instead of absolute paths in your programs that your code is looking for a file (like "emoticons.data") in the directory of the executing program (in this case, the script, NOT the module.) I would first try changing all file-paths to absolute paths in the program, or put the "emoticons.data" in your executing directory.

Answer (score 0):

There is a discrepancy between your error (`emoticons_file = open("emoticons.data","r")`) and the source code you reference (unsupervised_sentiment/datasets/emoticons_patch.py:23 is `emoticons_file = open("datasets/emoticons.data","r")`). but the basic problem is the same. The module attempts to open the file using a relative path name, which only works if you are executing from the project's directory.

If you update to the code I found in the repo, you must cd to `/Users/chlee021690/Desktop/Programming/Python/Recommender System/unsupervised_sentiment/` to run it.

To me, this is broken and the project maintainers should fix it.